# How to $sum and $filter in Mongodb aggregate (Group)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Trying to sum the above data with the group aggregate always return 0.

```
{
     team: "5d091e8b402c1d089042000d"
     _id: "5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4a7"
     goals: [
      {
        player: "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c"
        createdAt: "1970-01-01T00:18:31.111+00:00"
        value: 1
        _id: 5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4aa
      },
      {
        player: "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c"
        createdAt: "1970-01-01T00:18:31.111+00:00"
        value: 1
        _id: 5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4aa
      }
     ]
    }

    {
     team: "5d091e8b402c1d089042000d"
     _id: "5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4a7"
     goals: [
      {
        player: "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c"
        createdAt: "1970-01-01T00:18:31.111+00:00"
        value: 1
        _id: 5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4aa
      },
      {
        player: "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c"
        createdAt: "1970-01-01T00:18:31.111+00:00"
        value: 1
        _id: 5d2e63ce89be227d171eb4aa
      }
     ]
    }
```

Current Try:

```
{
  _id: "$team",
    total: { 
      "$sum": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$goals", 
            "as": "s",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$s.player", "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c"] }
        }  
      }
    }
}
```

the above returns:

```
{ _id: 5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c, total: 0}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to move filtering as a separate pipeline stage and then run double `$sum` (inner one sums the array from single document, outer aggregates cross-document value)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            goals: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$goals",
                    as: "g",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$g.player", "5d20636a4b0bf2670c1e014c" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$team",
            total: { $sum: { $sum: "$goals.value" } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9_cQSH-fWbu)

Comment: Hi @mickl what does $$this mean in this context? However, the above-proposed solution doesn't return the total.

Comment: $$this means currently processed element,  here's how I tested that: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WEX8DiLDAAI

Comment: @micki I have updated the data on MongoDB play and also my question with a picture for the sake of clarity. Meanwhile, it is still not working on my machine and also let me know why you use $project instead of Group.

Comment: @AlexOnozor my apologies, I misunderstood your question, modified my answer